# Formatting the result set in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

Below is my query to get the space details:

```
$myarray += $finaldata

foreach ($dr in $Drive) 
{
Switch ($dr)
{
E { $myarray | select  Servername,EDriveFreeSpace | ft}
H { $myarray | select  Servername,HDriveFreeSpace | ft}
I { $myarray | select  Servername,IDriveFreeSpace | ft}
O { $myarray | select  Servername,ODriveFreeSpace | ft}
}
} 

}


if(!$Drive)
{
$myarray |ft
}

}
```

Output:

```
Servername      EDriveFreeSpace
CVRFDGXXXX1             734
CVRFDGXXXX2             986

Servername      ODriveFreeSpace
CVRFDGXXXX1             547
CVRFDGXXXX2             718
```

Can I get the result set in below format:

```
Servername EDriveFressSpace  ODriveFressSpace
CVRFDGXXXX1             734               547
CVRFDGXXXX2             986               718
```

Any changes I need to do to get output in the above format, Any suggestions would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Remove `ft` from all the statements

Comment: I fremoved ft getting in below format :
     Servername      EDriveFreeSpace

     CVRFDGXXXX1             734
     CVRFDGXXXX1                           
     CVRFDGXXXX1             734
     CVRFDGXXXX2             986
     CVRFDGXXXX1                    
      CVRFDGXXXX2

Comment: That's because you're narrowing it down to just those 2 properties being returned. You need to check to see if those drives do exist, then output the returned values.

Comment: Script is a function which should give output for the result I am fetching for, result is fetching in multi lines for each drive but I am looking at in single liner

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you're looking for this (using the full name of the cmdlet that alias `ft` refers to, [`Format-Table`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/format-table)):

```bash
$myArray | Format-Table -Property ServerName, [EHIO]FreeDriveFreeSpace
```

This assumes that at least the first object in `$myArray` has *all* the properties whose name the [wildcard expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Wildcards) `[EHIO]FreeDriveFreeSpace` matches.

If that condition isn't met, you can use an aux. [`Select-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object) call to construct custom objects that *do* have all these properties:

```bash
$myArray | 
  Select-Object -Property ServerName, EFreeDriveFreeSpace, HFreeDriveFreeSpace, IFreeDriveFreeSpace, OFreeDriveFreeSpace |
  Format-Table
```

Comment: am getting empty result if used above condition

Comment: @StarHunt, if you get no output at all, `$myArray` presumably has no value. Be sure that it contains a collection whose objects have the properties shown in your question.